# HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized in Response Headers in Load runner for GET Requests

Tags: web-services, cookies, performance-testing, load-testing, loadrunner

I am new to Load runner , Am facing am issue while play back of the script

LR 12.50

O.S Windows 7 SP2

Protocol is Mobile HTTP/HTML

Recording mode is Proxy

Let me explain my scenario

While executing following function:

```
  web_custom_request("authenticate", 

        "URL=https://ws-xx.xxx.com/tcs/rest/authenticate?include=user,company",     
        "Method=POST", 
        "Resource=0", 
        "RecContentType=application/json", 
        "Referer=", 
        "Snapshot=t1.inf", 
        "Mode=HTTP", 
        "EncType=application/json",
        "Body={\"password\":\"xxx\",\"username\":\"xxx\",\"version\":\"1.0.40\"}", 
        LAST);
```

For the above POST method , am getting response as below

```
   HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
   Date: Tue, 13 Oct 2015 19:19:21 GMT\r\n
   Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1\r\n
   Content-Type: application/json\r\n
   Set-Cookie: dtCookie=DBE9311E44E5C47902702DC762030583|TXlBcHB8MQ; Path=/;
   Domain=.xxx.com\r\n    
   Connection: close\r\n
   Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n
```

Which is fine ,Now the second custom request is shown below

```
  web_custom_request("profiles", 
        "URL=https://ws-test.xxx.com/tcs/rest/profiles", 
        "Method=GET", 
        "Resource=1", 
        "RecContentType=application/json", 
        "Referer=", 
        "Snapshot=t2.inf", 
        LAST);
```

For the above GET requests  in the replay logs am getting:

> 401 unauthorized error.

```
 GET /tcs/rest/profiles HTTP/1.1\r\n

     User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT)\r\n

    Accept: */*\r\n

    Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n

     Host: ws-test.xxx.com\r\n

   Cookie: dtCookie=DBE9311E44E5C47902702DC762030583|TXlBcHB8MQ\r\n
\r\n
 t=5921ms: 172-byte response headers for "https://ws-test.xxx.com/tcs/rest/profiles" (RelFrameId=1, Internal ID=2)

    HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized\r\n

   Date: Tue, 13 Oct 2015 19:19:22 GMT\r\n

   Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1\r\n

   Content-Type: application/json\r\n

    Connection: close\r\n

    Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n
   \r\n

t=5922ms: 4-byte chunked response overhead for "https://ws-test.xxx.com/tcs/rest/profiles" (RelFrameId=1, Internal ID=2)
    8b\r\n

 t=5923ms: 139-byte chunked response body for "https://ws-test.xxx.com/tcs/rest/profiles" (RelFrameId=1, Internal ID=2)
     {"errors":[{"message":"Authentication required to access endpoint","status":"401","code":"



 NotAuthenticated","header":"Not Authenticated"}]}
```

I refereed [this link](http://www.sqaforums.com/showflat.php?Number=645138).

My understanding from the above custom request , login is success but the next
 subsequent requests are getting failed.

I have used web_cleanup_cookies() function but didn't solve the issue .

I tried to capture the Cookie ID using the below function

```
web_reg_save_param("COOKIE_ID",
                        "LR= Cookie: dtCookie=" ,
                        "RB= |TXlBcHB8MQ\r\n",
                        "Ord=All",
                        "RelFrameId=1",
                        "Search=All",
                        LAST);

web_add_header("Cookie",lr_eval_string("{COOKIE_ID}"));
```

Now question is where to place parameter "COOKIE_ID" in my script while there is

no value in script for COOKIE_ID?

How to handle this issue ? Can anybody please help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In Vugen, Select snapshot view and compare both record and replay requests, suspecting there might be a missing of header in replay request.
2. If cookie is the only thing changing you can add it by using web_add_cookie function.

Comment: @ Sivaramaraju , Thanks for your suggestion. Using snapshot view I found that authToken ("authToken":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJUQ1MiLCJhdWQiOiJXZWJTZXJ2aWNlQVBJIiwiaWF0IjoxNDQ0Mzg1ODU2LCJleHAiOjE0NDQ
0NzIyNTYsImluZm8iOnsidXNlcklkIjoxODIsImNvbXBhbnlOdW1iZXIiOiIyMDIwMDIyIiwicHJvZmlsZUlkIjoyODF9fQ.3pP9URRrmnRHnueszw4TrzDazPjRLmhG6bRir_FftAM") is getting passed to the next custom request. i.e GET requests which is dynamic.Can you please tel me how to handle this .

Comment: How it was going, as a header or cookie? Based on that follow below steps,
1. If it’s going in header, Correlate authentication token, then add web_add_header(“authToken”,”value”); before particular request.
2.  If  it’s going in cookie, Correlate authentication token, then add web_add_header(“cookie”,”authToken=value”); before particular request.

Comment: then Correlate authentication token and use web_add_header(“authToken”,”{correlatedvalue}”);

Comment: @ Sivaramaraju, Thanks a lot for your help . Finally using your approach solved the authToken issue which we were facing.However I did correlate the authToken value but vas throwing error couldn't find value for parameter.But I have hard coded theauthToken value as web_add_header("Authorization","Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJUQ1MiLCJhdWQiOiJXZWJTZXJ2aWNlQVBJIiwiaWF0IjoxNDQ1MjQ2MjI1LCJleHAiOjE0NDUzMzI2MjUsImluZm8iOnsidXNlcklkIjoxMjUsImNvbXBhbnlOdW1iZXIiOiIyMDIwMDIyIiwicHJvZmlsZUlkIjoxOTV9fQ.lttdyOk2Ed52Ha5Q5rNy2hiR8jUywmvlICR3wY01kU");Am not sure whether this is good approach or not ?

Comment: @ Sivaramaraju , By hard coding the authToken , the GET requests are getting passed. It solved my problem but am not sure whether it is a good approach to do in this way or not . Can you please give your suggestion.

Comment: check with developers whether authentication token is hard coded value or  it will change dynamically. if it changes dynamically you have to correlate that.

Answer (score 2):

Please add below headers to the script

```
web_set_sockets_option("SSL_VERSION","TLS");
web_set_user("username", "password", "domain:portno" );
web_set_sockets_option("INITIAL_BASIC_AUTH","1");
```

Comment: @ NaveenKumar , Thanks for  your suggestion.  I tried using web_set_sockets_option("INITIAL_BASIC_AUTH","1"); then I was able to see the  AuthToken under snapshot view  in Header then as per Sivaramaraju suggestion. I was able to pass the authToken to the next GET requests but hardcoding it.